# ASP.NET and Crystal Report

Tags: asp.net

Where i could get Sample Project in Crystal Report of Asp.Net. I have already visited http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227521%28v=VS.80%29.aspx site, I prefer different one.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio and Crystal Reports are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here you can find a good beginner tutorial

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Using-Crystal-Reports.aspx

and some code snippets

http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/Category542.aspx